# rails 4. Javascript syntax appearring online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to append a view when a user click on "New comment" but instead I'm getting the output of the javascript.

comment/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "new comment", new_article_comment_path(@article, :format => :js), :remote => true, :id => 'new_comment_link' %>
```

new.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'comments/new.html.erb') %>").insertAfter('#comments');
$('#new_comment').hide().slideDown();
$('#new_comment_link').hide();
```

The output is leading me to new.js.erb somehow:

```
$("<form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/articles/3/comments\" class=\"new_comment\" id=\"new_comment\" method=\"post\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"zSq3KpEbucFQLa6XStEJ/I0+CpKPLFYcU/WGIdneeMg=\" /><\/div>\n<div class=\"field\">\n<label for=\"comment_name\">Name<\/label><br />\n<input id=\"comment_name\" name=\"comment[name]\" type=\"text\" />\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"field\">\n<label for=\"comment_email\">Email<\/label><br />\n<input id=\"comment_email\" name=\"comment[email]\" type=\"text\" />\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"field\">\n<label for=\"comment_body\">Body<\/label><br />\n<textarea id=\"comment_body\" name=\"comment[body]\">\n<\/textarea>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"actions\">\n<input name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" />\n<\/div>\n<\/form>").insertAfter('#comments');
$('#new_comment').hide().slideDown();
$('#new_comment_link').hide();
```

Comment: I guess _new.html.erb is your partial. Try it... $("<%= j render '/comments/new.html.erb' %>").insertAfter('#comments');

Comment: Sorry it's not supposed to be a partial it's a simple view new.html.erb

Comment: When I'm on show.html and I click on "New Comment" instead of appending the new.html it redirects me at new.js (the javascript erb file)

Comment: Try removing format: js in the link.
<%= link_to "new comment", new_article_comment_path(@article), :remote => true, :id => 'new_comment_link' %>

Comment: removing format: js works! But it doesn't append the content after the id="comment" instead it replace the hole body content. I'm on http://0.0.0.0:3000/articles/4 when I click I'm supposed to stay at the same page but .... I'm on http://0.0.0.0:3000/articles/4/comments/new

Comment: $("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'comments/new.html.erb').html_safe %>").insertAfter('#comments');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use **:handlers** and **:formats** in *render* method, this method works for me.

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'comments/new', :handlers => [:erb], :formats => [:html]) %>").insertAfter('#comments');
$('#new_comment').hide().slideDown();
$('#new_comment_link').hide();
```

add `format.js` to your create method in comments controller

```
def create
 @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
 if @comment.save
  redirect_to @article, :notice => 'Thanks for your comment'
  format.js # default to render 'create.js.erb'
 else
  redirect_to @article, :alert => 'Unable to add comment'
  format.js { render 'create_failed.js.erb' }
 end
end
```

Comment: Thks Qi Li. Yes this method is working too is doing the same thing as " Bachan Smruty"but I still have a redirect 0.0.0.0:3000/articles/4/comments/new. I'm supposed to stay at the same page.

Comment: did you add `format.js` code line in your comments controller (new method)?